# Date names between two week abbreviation js

Tags: javascript

What is the best way by JS to get week days between two week abbreviation:

```
 So for SUN-WED receive SUN,MON,TUE,WED
 For MON-FRI receive MON,TUE,WED,FRI
```

Comment: what did you try?

Answer (score 0):

Get first and last day by JS function split("-");

Make a new 13-length-array SUN, MON, TUE, ..., SAT, SUN, MON, ... , FRI.

And loop that array to find the first date.

After that, collect items into another array or string with comma until finding the last date.

You will even receive SAT, SUN, MON, TUE, ... THU, FRI as SAT-FRI.

I wish this will help you.

Comment: Thank you, why its need to create 13-length? Not  7?

Comment: the first day would be later than the last day. like SAT-MON. If you don't need it, its length maybe 7.

Comment: And after i find last day in arry  exit from loop with break?

Comment: you are right. can I contact you with another route? Skype, etc.